# ElasticSearch Java Request to get documents expiring in next x days

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, ttl

I'm new to ElasticSearch, so please go easy on me. I have looked on elastic.co  and googled a lot to figure out the right Java filter and query to apply to be able to pull only the documents that will expire in the next x days, where x is a value passed in by the user of the application and is also the ttl set on each of the documents in Elastic.

I've tried various filters like rangeFilter, boolFilter on the FilterBuilders that pass in the request to Elastic like:

```
Raw Source: {
"from" : 0,
"size" : 20, "filter" : {
"bool" : {
  "should" : {
    "range" : {
      "_ttl" : {
        "from" : 2000,
        "to" : 2160000000,
        "include_lower" : false,
        "include_upper" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
},
  "explain" : false,
  "fields" : [ "_ttl", "_source" ],
  "sort" : [ {
    "created" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Java code for the search is as follows:

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb = client.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type).addFields("_ttl", "_source")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setExplain(false);

        if (query != null) srb.setQuery(query);
        if (filter != null) srb.setPostFilter(filter);

        LOG.debug("Raw Source: {}\n", srb.toString());

        // Fetch the Document response from the index
        SearchResponse response = srb.execute().actionGet();
```

where filter that gets passed in is:

```
(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().should(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter(_ttl).gt(2000).lte(2160000000)));
```

Other params like query, index, type are passed in to the code. Currently only index and type get passed to the code and not query (null)

The above query to Elastic yields zero hits, so obviously something is amiss. I do have multiple documents that expire within 15 days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: Using version 0.90.10

Answer (score 0):

When using the `_ttl` field in a range query, you need to specify from/to which represent millisecond values and not days.

So in your case you should do something like this and it will work:

```
// from now
long from = System.currentTimeMillis();
// to 15 days from now
long to = from + (15 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
   .should(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("_ttl")
       .gt(from)
       .lt(to));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get back 0 hits.

Comment: Can you share the raw source you're generating and eventually, your latest Java code as well?

Comment: It'd be better if you update your question with these, it would be more legible.

Comment: Also can you show how you indexed the documents with the TTL value of 15 days?

Comment: I've updated the original question with Raw Source and Java code. We have thousands of documents whose time to live vary from a few days to a year (15 days was an example I was using). We've updated mapping of the documents to enable _ttl and then set the _ttl in milliseconds on the docs while indexing (by first converting days into milliseconds). 

        client.prepareIndex(index, type, id).setTTL(newttl).setSource(payload).execute().actionGet();

Thanks.

Comment: it's weird, but at the same time you're using such an old version of ES, that it wouldn't surprise me if that was a bug that's been fixed in the meantime. I will dust off my old 0.90 instance and try in a moment, but you should really consider upgrading to at least the latest ES 1.7 release.

Comment: We are in the process of moving to 2.2, but it's at least a couple months away.

Comment: You need to specify the time in milliseconds not in seconds, i.e. `2160000000000` instead of `216000000` and it will work.

Comment: The number, 2160000000 I have in my query is in milliseconds, it converts to 25 days (2160000000 millis/86400000 millis in a day) and that's the number I want to use for my search query. Could this be a version thing like you were suggesting yesterday? I wonder if there is something wrong with the filter?

Comment: The from/to numbers you use for your `_ttl` range query need to milliseconds values from the epoch, see in my answer above, from is the number of milliseconds from the epoch for "now" and to is the number of milliseconds 15 days later from "now".

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!! I didn't get a chance to test out your suggestion till about an hour or so ago. So, passing in the # of millis from epoch for 'now' (from) and # of millis 15 days later from 'now' (to) did the trick! And it works in version 0.90.10 :)